# how do I get the UTC milliseconds for today at 6:15PM?

Tags: android, calendar

How do I get the UTC milliseconds for today at a given time, say 6:15PM?

I want that as a start time then I will use the GPS getTime() function and be able to compute how much time until my start as the race committee always uses GPS time.

Looking at this documentation [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29), I would think I would just need to call Calendar(); then get(MONTH), get(YEAR), etc and do a set(year, month, day, 18, 15,0); but that doesn't work.

Maybe it is Calendar.YEAR, etc but I have not figured out the set equivalent and I get warnings.

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Look at the Joda library http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// get calendar instance, substitute timezone for which ever you need or leave blank to use current
Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Pacific"));

updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18); // set hour
updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);      // set minute
updateTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);       // set seconds

long time = updateTime.getTimeInMillis(); // get milliseconds
```

Comment: Did you understand the question?

Comment: Honesty idk if your being serious or facetious.

Comment: Thank you @Jug6ernaut.  That worked perfectly.  You saved me so much time.

Comment: I added updateTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); to make it right on the minute.  BTW, I cannot find any official documentation that has "updateTime" listed even after having this post as guidance.  Thanks again @Jug6ernaut, I never would have found it without your help.

Comment: Ahh yes .set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); does make it exact, i will add to answer. "updateTime" is just a random the variable name.

Comment: @Jug6ernaut Of course --  updateTime is defined in Calendar call.  Thanks once again.  I almost have the timer part of the app working.  This is all very cool.

Comment: @Jug6ernaut, I asked because i didn't understand exactly what he was asking, not as a critic to your answer. ;) it's still a duplicate though, but that's another matter. And was impressed with the rather fast answer, that's all.

Comment: ahh ok :), just thought it was an odd response lol. All good.